# Warning (2): filesize(): stat failed for index.jpg [CORE/Cake/Utility/Validation.php, line 996] in cakephp 2.6

Tags: php, cakephp

I am trying to upload image in folder using cakephp 2.6. After successfully upload image in folder below error(warning) is coming:-

> Warning (2): filesize(): stat failed for index.jpg
>   [CORE/Cake/Utility/Validation.php, line 996]

And i want to tell you above error is coming only if i am using validation regarding to image upload in model. In case if i comment image filesize validation on model, above error will disappear.
What am i doing wrong here?

Code is:

Model Name: `User.php`

```
class User extends AppModel{

public $validate =array(  

'image' => array(
        'mimetype'=>array(
            'rule' => array('extension', array('gif','jpg','jpeg','png')),
            'message' => 'Please apply only (gif, jpg, jpeg, png) file type.'
        ), 
        'checksize'=>array(
            'rule'=>array('fileSize', '<' , '50MB'),
            'message'=> 'Image can not exceed to 1 MB.'
        )
    )
);
```

Controller is: `UsersController.php`

```
<?php
 class UsersController extends AppController {

public function index() {          
    $this->loadModel('User'); //load model      
    if($this->request->is('post')){ 

        // trimming the all post values - Apply a user function recursively to every member of an array
        array_walk_recursive($this->request->data, function(&$val, $key) {
                            $val = trim($val);
        });

        $this->User->set($this->request->data); //set data to model
        if ($this->User->validates()){
            $datas = array(
                    'User' => array(
                                'name' => $this->request->data['fname'],
                                'email'=>$this->request->data['email'],
                                'password'=>$this->request->data['pwd'],
                                'image'=>$this->request->data['image']['name']
                        )
                    );  
            $pathToUpload=  WWW_ROOT . 'upload/';           
            move_uploaded_file($this->request->data['image']['tmp_name'],$pathToUpload.$this->request->data['image']['name']);                      
            // prepare the model for adding a new entry
            $this->User->create();
            // save the data
            if($this->User->save($datas)){
                $this->Session->setFlash('User Information has been saved!');
                //return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            }
        } else {
            $errors = $this->User->validationErrors; //handle errors    
        }   
    }

    //$this->layout = NULL;
    $this->viewpPath='Users';
    $this->render('add');
}
 }
```

And View:  `add.ctp`

```
<h1>ADD USER</h1>
<?php
 $errors = $this->Form->validationErrors;
 $flatErrors = Set::flatten($errors);
 if(count($errors['User']) > 0) {
 ?>
  <div>
     <ul>
        <?php
            foreach($flatErrors as $key => $value) { ?>
                <li style='color:red;'><?php echo($value); ?></li>
        <?php } ?>
     </ul>
     </div>
   <?php
     }

     echo $this->Form->create('User',array('type'=>'file'));
     ?>
     FullName: <input type='text' name='fname'/>
     <br>
     Email: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <input type='text' name='email'/>
     <br>
      Password: <input type='password' name='pwd'/>
     <br>
     Confirm Password: <input type='password' name='cpwd'/>
     <br>
     Upload Image: <input type='file' name='data[image]' />
     <br>
     <input type='submit' name='save' value='Submit'/>
     <?php
       echo $this->Form->end();
      ?>
```

Comment: It's not a good idea to mix helper usage with plain html like that - your submitted data is probably malformed - i.e. look at what `$this->request->data` is in your controller action.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Actually i am new in CakePhp and this is my first project.